# how to save a captured screenshot locally in chrome plugin?

Tags: file, screen-capture

how to save a captured screenshot locally in chrome plugin? 
I m stuck badly. 
If it can be done by only npapi than please give me some examples. Please do help me.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to go about saving the file locally but you can capture a screenshot of the current tab with the [`captureVisibleTab` method](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab). It returns a JPG image encoded as a data URI.

Comment: Thanx for that. I found out that if i have to do this I have to use the npapi plugin. But i have no clue how to do that. if you know than please tell me how i can do that . thanxs again